# I have found this error while am adding data to quickbase database?

Tags: quickbase

I am new for quickbase , i am adding a data into my quickbase database and i have fond the resut as

```
<qdbapi><action>API_AddRecord</action><errcode>34</errcode><errtext>You cannot change the value of this field</errtext><errdetail>The field named "Customer Name" with field id 264 cannot be modified</errdetail><udata>mydata</udata><ticket>6_bgxe7d289_bv3b7j_b_b32jss8dsypt66cgs2ujxcrqmqshb2b5yw2dc45zgzd4i8e9ydzemkyu</ticket></qdbapi>
```

Could any one told me that how can add data .

Comment: See http://www.quickbase.com/api-guide/index.html#errorcodes.html - without knowing the source, this is likely not answerable.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you get this error when you are trying to change a Lookup field or a formula field. Those fields have values that are dependent on other fields, so you cannot change them manually.